# Mappling Multiple Tables To Entity In EF5

Tags: entity-framework

Edited For Clarity:

Im working on a webapp build ontop of an existing DB in which i may not change the schema. Much of the data i need is pulled across multiple tables, linked by FKs

How can i create entities in EF that pull from multiple tables (most have a 1 to 0/1 constraint) to more easily work with the data I need.

For example I have 2 employees table, one with account info, and one that if populated is demographic information. If none was input then a record for that employee will not exist in that DB.

What i tried (with no success so far) was create my own "Employee" entity, imported user table, and user_demographic table. Then cut \ paste the properties i wanted into my Employee Entity, and mapped the tables, when i added the demographic table I set the PK of the demo table to the FK of the user table, however when i try to validate this EF complains about fragment mappings?

Comment: You don't necessarily have to create update functions if the views are writable, i.e. don't have grouping or other features that prevent data updates.  If you showed the schema someone might be able to say with more certainty.  What is the back-end platform?

Comment: Back end is SQL. I was just going to write views that would pull in all i need and map that, but it seems like the "better" way would be to keep all the logic stuff in the EF layer, no?

Comment: Can you create views against the tables?  If you are "not allowed to change the schema", you may still be allowed to create views, since they don't necessarily impact the rest of the DB design.

Comment: I was trying to keep the data layer for my application out of the database level, such that say the database was removed and restored by the vendor the app would just 'work' assuming none of their table names or column names changed....

Is this something EF can handle? Or does it really need to be mapped to actually tables/views?